# SQL Prevent Multiple Counting

Tags: sql, count

I found some similar SO questions regarding my issue and they fixed it by using sub-queries but I can't seem to apply it on my situation.

#### Goal

My goal is to count the animals that have been a breeder at least once in their lifespan.

I have 2 tables to keep track of when an animal became a breeder. Here's a simple look of how the tables are structured:

#### Animals (a)

```
id     name
-------------------
100    Mouse
101    Cow
102    Pig
103    Dog
```

#### Breeding History (bh)

```
id     animal_id     code     date
--------------------------------------------
500    100           B        2016-01-12
501    100           A        2016-01-25
502    101           B        2016-01-28
503    102           B        2016-02-02
504    100           B        2016-02-05
505    100           A        2016-02-08
```

In this scenario, my current query for counting works fine for both `101 | Cow` and `102 | Pig` since they only became a breeder `(Code: B)` once. The count for an animal who never became a breeder is also correct but it's not really a problem here. For an animal that became a breeder more than once in its lifespan e.g. `100 | Mouse` it would be counted by the number of times it became a breeder.

#### Query

```
SELECT
    a.name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN bh.code IN ('B') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS breeder_count
FROM animals a
LEFT OUTER JOIN breeding_history bh
    ON a.id = bh.animal_id
GROUP BY a.name
```

#### Result

```
name     breeder_count
--------------------------
Mouse    2
Cow      1
Pig      1
Dog      0
```

The result shows that there are 2 mice that became a breeder when actually it was the same animal and should only be counted once.

Comment: Will there ever be a case where that number is not 1 or 0? Are you actually counting anything or is it simply a yes/no?

Comment: @TomH There will be cases when the value is greater than 1 if we take into account the species and the strain of the animals but to simplify the question I made it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DISTINCT` keyword, so as to count a `'B'` just once:

```
SELECT
    a.name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN bh.code IN ('B') THEN 1 END) AS breeder_count
FROM animals a
LEFT OUTER JOIN breeding_history bh
    ON a.id = bh.animal_id
GROUP BY a.name
```

As a side note, `ELSE NULL` is redundant and has been removed from the `CASE` expression.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/333a9/1)

Comment: @downvoter I really don't understand the reason for downvoting a correct answer. Care to express the arguments you based your vote on?

Comment: I didn't downvote. I actually upvoted this and accepted as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I believe your `case` needs to return `a.id` rather than `1` so each animal can be counted once and not each animal type/name. I was not downvoter.

Comment: `CASE` uses `bh.code` that is either 'A', or 'B'. Using `1` with `DISTINCT` guarantees that `B`s are counted just once per animal `name`.

Comment: @Giorgos Based on the sample data you're right. Hopefully OP understands what 's going on and adapts accordingly.

Comment: @shawnt00 No worries, I understand what's happening here.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but I don't think that your SQL does what you think it does. It's not actually counting anything, it's effectively just giving you an exists/not exists flag. If you introduce the variant into the picture as the OP talks about then your statement will break down.

Comment: @TomH No worries. I applied the query to actual live data and I'm not getting just `1`s and `0`s. I'm getting the right results.

Comment: @TomH My code checks for existence / not existence of 'B's and I think this is the intention of the OP. This is what I tried to explain in my comment above perhaps not so successfully.

Comment: Scrap that, I was looking at the wrong column, lol. Yeah I'm only getting `1`s and `0`s. I had to change `THEN 1` into `THEN bh.animal_id` in conjunction with `DISTINCT` to make it work.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio OK, my bad, I had not seen your reply to Tom's comment. I'm glad you got it working!